# Istio ingress gateway, getting 403 forbidden error

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, istio, azure-aks

I am trying to follow the istio gateway and Virtual Service guide at - https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-control/#determining-the-ingress-ip-and-ports

I can see that these resources (Gateway & VS) are created from Kiali and also from command line. When I try to access my endpoint at `curl -I -HHost:httpbin.example.com http://$INGRESS_HOST:$INGRESS_PORT/status/200` I get a `403 Forbidden error`.

I am looking at the istio-proxy logs at
k logs httpbin-pod -c istio-proxy -n my-bookinfo
and dont see much there.  I am trying to figure out where I can start to debug the issue. Any ideas? (edited)

[image]

Comment: check the logs of `istio-ingresssgateway`.

Comment: does your service work? so is it up? you did create all the istio resources? how did you install istio? did you label the namespace to inject sidecars? does it work? can you confirm that?

Answer (score 2):

I guess the `HTTP 403` issue might be connected with Istio *[Authorization](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/security/#authorization)* or *[Authentication](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/security/#authentication)* mesh configurations, assuming that you've successfully injected [Envoy](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/what-is-istio/#envoy) sidecar into the particular Pod or widely across related namespaces.

The logs inspection might be most issue explainable task, confirming that [Envoy's Access Logs](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/telemetry/logs/access-log/) are already enabled, you can look through relevant `istio-proxy` sidecar and `istio-ingressgateway` Pod logs; whereas you can fetch [Envoy proxy](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/observability/access_log#command-operators) response flags and traffic path workflow:

```
$ kubectl logs -l app=httpbin -c istio-proxy
```

> [2019-03-06T09:31:27.360Z] "GET /status/418 HTTP/1.1" 418 - "-" 0 135
>   5 2 "-" "curl/7.60.0" "d209e46f-9ed5-9b61-bbdd-43e22662702a"
>   "httpbin:8000" "127.0.0.1:80"
>   inbound|8000|http|httpbin.default.svc.cluster.local - 172.30.146.73:80
>   172.30.146.82:38618 outbound_.8000_._.httpbin.default.svc.cluster.local

Check *[Authentication Policies](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/security/authn-policy/)* within a mesh, that can affect sidecars proxy behavior and revise a global mesh policy in terms of [mTLS](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/security/#mutual-tls-authentication) authentication, [Permissive](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/security/#authorization-permissive-mode) mode is enabled by default:

`$ kubectl get policies.authentication.istio.io --all-namespaces`

`$ kubectl get meshpolicy.authentication.istio.io default -oyaml`

If you launched *[Authorization](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/security/#enabling-authorization)* rules within a mesh, verify all the corresponded RBAC policies:

`$ kubectl get clusterrbacconfigs.rbac.istio.io --all-namespaces`

```
$ kubectl get authorizationpolicies.rbac.istio.io,rbacconfigs.rbac.istio.io,servicerolebindings.rbac.istio.io,serviceroles.rbac.istio.io --all-namespaces
```

Find more related information about troubleshooting steps in the official Istio [documentation](https://istio.io/docs/ops/troubleshooting/security-issues/).