# why does istio gives ISTIO-403 forbidden error

Tags: kubernetes, istio

After implementing istio, the service which was working before on browser has started giving 403 forbidden error.please note that this service still works inside k8 cluster and gives 200 response but on the browser it responds with 403 forbidden when it is called from other service.

what could be the reason?

any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you check logs: `kubectl logs -f <POD_NAME> -c istio-proxy` ?
Additionally, take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58116747/14801225) - it may help to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

By fixing the http_upgrade in nginx.this issue got resolved